# /authorize or /login/callback endless loop

Tags: okta, pkce, okta-signin-widget

We have a react app using auth code with pkce . When user is not assigned to an App they are getting an endless loop to /login/callback and /authorize endpoint with error “User is not assigned to an app” . I don’t understand why I’m getting the loop . This is causing Okta rate violation limit .
[Click here to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RSfR.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't leave code as image! See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `Everyone` group to your app and it should solve the problem.